# Do JavaScript Static Variables stay present once control leaves the script?

Tags: javascript, variables, static

I have a question about static variables in JavaScript. Do they only last during the scope of the script? What I mean is what if control leaves the script and goes back to the html code, are the static variables still there?

Comment: yes they are still there.  If you were to reload the page, any global values get reloaded then.

Comment: How are you declaring a "static" variable in Javascript? Variables that are static, remain the same across all instances of the script. For instance, if you have an hourly rate that is static, and set to $45/hour, it would be $45 at the beginning and throughout all calls to any methods. Static variables are assigned before program execution, hence how they all have the same value with each and every instance of the program execution.

Comment: I'm declaring them as fields within objects. So I should I declare at the beginning of my program before I write any code? Can't I declare them within a function?

Comment: If they are declared within the code block of a function, they are local to that function and will be destroyed when the function exits. If they are declared outside a function, they will persist even when updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean global instead of static variables. Global variables are declared in the global document scope. They are accessible from all methods (functions) and when you modify their value from within a function's code block, the value persists, since you are modifying the global variable.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    global_var = 0; // declared globally
    function global_inc(){
        global_var += 1; // global var incremented by 1
    }

    function local_inc(){
        local_var = global_var; // declared locally, and scope ends at function end.
        local_var += 1; // local var incremented by 1
        alert('global: ' + global_var);
        alert('local: ' + local_var);
    }

    function alert_global(){
        alert('global: ' + global_var);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert_global(); // alert global (0)
    global_inc(); // increment global to 1
    local_inc(); // set local to global (1) and increment local to (2), alert both
    alert_global(); // alert global (1)
</script>
```

You would get: 
alert of "global: 0" from alert_global() 
alert of "global: 1" from local_inc() 
alert of "local: 2" from local_inc() 
alert of "global: 1" from alert_global()